# How to print results from this function

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to Python and programming in general and  need a little help with this (partially finished) function. It's calling a text file with a bunch of rows of comma delimited data  (age, salary, education and so on). However, I've run into a problem from the outset. I don't know how to return the results.

My aim is to create dictionaries for each category and for each row to be sorted and tallied.

e.g. 100 people over 50, 200 people under 50 and so on.

Am I in the correct ball park?

```
file = "adultdata.txt"

def make_data(file):
    try:
       f = open(file, "r")
    except IOError as e:
       print(e)
       return none

large_list = []

avg_age = 0
row_count_under50 = 0
row_count_over50 = 0

#create 2 dictionaries per category

employ_dict_under50 = {}
employ_dict_over50 = {}

for row in f:
    edited_row = row.strip()
    my_list = edited_row.split(",")
    try:
        #Age Category
        my_list[0] = int(my_list[0])

        #Work Category
        if my_list[-1] == " <=50K":
           if my_list[1] in employ_dict_under50:
               employ_dict_under50[my_list[1]] += 1
           else:
              employ_dict_under50[my_list[1]] = 1
              row_count_u50 += 1

        else:
           if my_list[1] in emp_dict_o50:
              employ_dict_over50[my_list[1]] += 1
           else:
              employ_dict_over50[my_list[1]] = 1 
              row_count_o50 += 1

# Other categories here


print(my_list)
#print(large_list)
#return 


# Ignored categories here - e.g. my_list[insert my list numbers here] = None
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not have access to your file but I had a go at correcting most of the errors you had in your code.

These are a list of the mistakes I found in your code:

- your function make_data is essentially useless and is out of scope. You need to remove it entirely
- When using a file object f, you need to use readline to extract data from the file.
- It is also best to use a `with` statement when using IO resources like files
- You had numerous variables which were badly named in the inner loop and did not exist
- You declared a try in the inner loop without a catch. You can remove the try because you are not trying to catch any Error

You have some very basic errors which are related to general programming, can I assume your new to this? If thats the case then you should probably follow some more beginner tutorials online until you get a grasp of what commands you need to use to perform basic tasks.

Try compare your code to this and see if you can understand what i'm trying to say:

```
file = "adultdata.txt"

large_list = []

avg_age = 0
row_count_under50 = 0
row_count_over50 = 0

#create 2 dictionaries per category

employ_dict_under50 = {}
employ_dict_over50 = {}

with open(file, "r") as f:
    row = f.readline()

    edited_row = row.strip()
    my_list = edited_row.split(",")
    #Age Category
    my_list[0] = int(my_list[0])

    #Work Category
    if my_list[-1] == " <=50K":
       if my_list[1] in employ_dict_under50:
           employ_dict_under50[my_list[1]] += 1
       else:
          employ_dict_under50[my_list[1]] = 1
          row_count_under50 += 1

    else:
       if my_list[1] in employ_dict_over50:
          employ_dict_over50[my_list[1]] += 1
       else:
          employ_dict_over50[my_list[1]] = 1
          row_count_over50 += 1

# Other categories here
print(my_list)
#print(large_list)
#return
```

I cannot say for certain if this code will work or not without your file but it should give you a head start.